# ZeroClipboard Plugin auto click

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

http://jsfiddle.net/5Ha9d/

I am using zeroclipboard plugin to add the text on click the submit button. Everything seems working but i want it to be automated for certain condition. I am not sure which is the correct way of triggering click event. I already tried with default as `$('#copy').click();`

I know it is in flash but i tried to know whether it is working or not but as long i unable to do this.

Here is the code i tried

```
                //set path
                ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/ZeroClipboard.swf');
                //create client
                var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
                //event
                clip.addEventListener('load', function () {
                    clip.setText(document.getElementById('box-content').value);
                });
                clip.addEventListener('complete', function (client, text) {
                    alert('copied: ' + text);
                });
                //glue it to the button
                clip.glue('copy');
jQuery('#copy').click();
```

Is there is a way to trigger this submit button on page load. Not sure is something straight forward.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Vicky

Answer (score 0):

According [to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058156/zeroclipboard-fire-click-event-via-jquery), you can't simulate a click on the flash object, and have it setData in the clipboard http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html#. It's a security precaution by Adobe.